# My formula is picks up the wrong information. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am doing a formula to show years of services of employees. For example:

- Person A (has 44 years of service)
- Person B has 15 Years of services

I have a timeline showing 5 yrs, 10 yrs, 15yrs...50yrs.
The formula I use picks up anything that is greater than the years I am looking for. (I need to show the year that is close to the person's year of service)

Formula used:

- Person A  `=IF((H3>45),"NO","Yes")`
- Person B `=IF((H3>15),"NO","Yes")`

another formula I used was
`=IF(H3>40,"H>40",IF(P1>40,"P>40","none>10"))`

Comment: What is your output? What would be the correct output?

Comment: Without sample data, together with the results you want and are getting, it is impossible to work out what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number of years of service is in `A1`, you can use the following formula to returns the number of years of service:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX({0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},MATCH(A1,{0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},1)), " years")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show the closest year of service rounded down to the nearest multiple of 5.

```
=(int(YearsOfService/5)*5)
```

Replace YearsOfService with your cell reference with the years of that person's service.